# Kotlin MutableMap has putIfAbsent method, does it extend Java's Map interface

Tags: java, kotlin

I am using Kotlin's `MutableMap` as below and IntelliJ Idea allowed me to call `putIfAbsent`
method on `MutableMap`. I don't see that method in Kotlin's `MutableMap` interface. I am confused why I was able to use that method which is from Java's Map interface ? Am I missing something here ?

```
 private val taggedImageMap: MutableMap<String, ImageEx> = mutableMapOf()

    init {
        images.forEach { taggedImage -> taggedImage.tags.forEach { taggedImageMap.putIfAbsent(it, taggedImage.image) } }
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you?  Yes, Kotlin's `MutableMap`s have all the methods from Java's Map.

Comment: I think this could be a naive question as I am new to Kotlin. But I did not see MutableMap Extending Java's map in collections.kt file which is a source code of Kotlin MutableMap interface.

Comment: [mapped-types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types)

Answer (score 2):

All `MutableMap`s are also `java.util.Map`s, but the relationship isn't "extending" that class -- it's more magical than that.  Kotlin treats some Java types specially, as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).  More or less, `MutableMap` *is the same as* `java.util.Map`.  Not only is every `MutableMap` a `java.util.Map`, but the reverse is also true, that any `java.util.Map` is also a `MutableMap`.

Comment: >the reverse is also true, that any java.util.Map is also a MutableMap< 
There's even more magic behind this. If you decompile an expression `m is MutableMap<*, *>`, you'll find a call to `TypeIntrinsics.isMutableMap`. [The sources show](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/internal/TypeIntrinsics.java#L201) that the actual check is `obj instanceof Map && (!(obj instanceof KMappedMarker) || obj instanceof KMutableMap);`

Comment: Thanks!  But, why not just have MutableMap actually implement java.util.Map?  Didn't want it to be to java-y?

Comment: Then _other_ implementations of `java.util.Map`, such as `HashMap`, wouldn't be `MutableMap`s and couldn't be passed to Kotlin.